# Linspace in numpy library

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I want to draw 3d lines using Python. I used Matplotlib, but I have a problem with the `linspace` function, and `Axes3D`. 
I already included MatplotLib and numpy library to the project.

this is the code :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

this picture will clarify the code bugs and the libraries: 
[picture](http://store1.up-00.com/2015-04/1429377578131.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is the problem with LineSpace Function ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "LineSpace Function" or why you think there's a problem with it. Can you clarify?

Comment: Ok, i will edit the Question and clarify it by picture, can you see it again, please

Comment: Have you tried to *run* the code? Please add the error message to your question.

Comment: You're code runs just fine. This problem seems to be only related to using eclipse.

Comment: this is the problems when try to run.
http://s2.postimg.org/riu0etsqx/Capture.png

Comment: what is the best IDE  to use instead of Eclips ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the screenshot you linked to in a comment, it looks like you don't have [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six), a dependency of matplotlib. You can download a six binary for windows [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#six).